# Get all records for each month. Impute if value not present for particular month and user. SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table of below format in sql

| UserId | Month | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | 4 | 12 |
| user1 | 6 | 2 |
| user1 | 12 | 2 |
| user2 | 1 | 4 |
| user2 | 7 | 5 |
| user2 | 9 | 6 |

I want it to display all month records for all users. If the month record for a user is not present then value for that month should be 0.

Output should be in below format:

| UserId | Month | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| user1 | 1 | 0 |
| user1 | 2 | 0 |
| user1 | 3 | 0 |
| user1 | 4 | 12 |
| user1 | 5 | 0 |
| user1 | 6 | 2 |
| user1 | 7 | 0 |
| user1 | 8 | 0 |
| user1 | 9 | 0 |
| user1 | 10 | 0 |
| user1 | 11 | 0 |
| user1 | 12 | 2 |
| user2 | 1 | 4 |
| user2 | 2 | 0 |
| user2 | 3 | 0 |
| user2 | 4 | 0 |
| user2 | 5 | 0 |
| user2 | 6 | 0 |
| user2 | 7 | 5 |
| user2 | 8 | 0 |
| user2 | 9 | 6 |
| user2 | 10 | 0 |
| user2 | 11 | 0 |
| user2 | 12 | 0 |

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using. I suggest you start by creating temporary tables that contain the 12 month values and the list of users, crossjoin them and then left join to your data table

Answer (score 2):

In sql server

```
CREATE TABLE #Months ([Month] INT)

DECLARE @i INT = 1

WHILE @i < 13
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO #Months ([Month]) VALUES (@i);
  SET @i = @i + 1
END

SELECT DISTINCT
  UserId,
  m.Month as Month,
  CASE 
    WHEN mt.Month = m.Month
      THEN mt.Value
    ELSE 0
    END AS [Value]
FROM #Months m
CROSS JOIN MyTable mt

DROP TABLE #Months
```

Comment: i think this option will create duplicate rows (12 * 6 in the example), as there is no limiting, the cross join will do a full cartesian

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the missing months by union them with the existing ones:

```
select * from yourtable y

union all

select distinct UserId, x.Months,0 from yourtable y
cross join 
(select months from (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)) T(months)) x
where not exists
(select 1 from yourtable y1 where y1.userid=y.userid and y1.month=x.months)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to generate the numbers from 1 to 12.  There are many ways, including:

- `select`/`union all`
- `values`
- a subquery
- recursive CTE
- numbers/tally table
- specific database functions

No single method works in all databases, but the closest is probably the first.

The idea is then to generate all the rows for all the ids and then bring in the existing data:

```
select u.userid, m.month, coalesce(t.value, 0) as value
from (select distinct userid from t) u cross join
     (select 1 as month union all
      select 2 as month union all
      . . .
     ) m left join
     t
     on t.userid = u.userid and t.month = m.month;
```

I should note that there are other approaches as well, but those are usually more closely tied to a specific database.